# Making requests to the server with jQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

There are several ways to make requests to the server using jQuery.

`.load()`
`.post()`
`.get()`
`.ajax()`

For uniformity throughout my application I always use `.ajax()`.

But I'm wondering if this really is a good approach.

So... is it?

Comment: It's fine if you don't mind the extra lines of code.

Comment: .get, .post, .getAjax are all shorthand helpers that use .ajax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other methods (`post`, `load`, and `get`) are just shorthand ways of invoking the `ajax` method, so it's a matter of style/convention.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with using ajax throughout your app.. I would infact advice this..

If I had to give a small analogy of get, post and ajax its like you would be able to buy yourself a completed car, with a friendly interface (pedals, steering wheel etc.) so you don't have to do it all yourself.

$.get, $.post etc. are used for higher-level abstractions that are often easier to understand and use, but don’t offer as much functionality (such as error callbacks).

To summarize:

```
$.load(): Load a piece of html into a container DOM.
$.get(): Use this if you want to make a GET call and play extensively with the response.
$.post(): Use this if you want to make a POST call and don’t want to load the response to some container DOM.
$.ajax(): Use this if you need to do something when XHR fails, or you need to specify ajax options (e.g. cache: true) on the fly.
```

Hope that makes sense..

Answer (score 2):

Its just a matter of preference, i myself have never used any of these short cuts.

`.load(), .post(), .get()` , are just short hands, internally they all relly on  `$.ajax`.

To test they all internally call `$.ajax`,  you can hack `$.ajax` as below

```
var capturedAjax= $.ajax;

$.ajax=function myCustomAjax(options)
{
     options.beforeSend=function()
     {
        alert('before send captured');
     }
     return capturedAjax(options);
}

 jQuery.get('http://google.com');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_prasad/LBBhf/

Answer (score 0):

Limiting yourself to only using `.ajax()` is a bad idea. Here is an analogy to explain why:

> Anna and Joe each  have a toolbox containing an all-in-one tool with all sorts of attachments, a belt sander, a power drill, a table saw, and a bunch of screws. They both need to build a wooden cabinet using the tools at their disposal and an ample supply of wood. Joe decides to use the all-in-one tool and simply change attachments as needed. Anna, however, realizes that it will be easier and faster to build the cabinet using tools made for a specific purpose and decides against using the all-in-one tool to do everything. Anna is able to build a better cabinet in less time because she chose to use tools designed for a specific purpose instead of the all-in-one tool.
>
> <sub>Analogy Updated to compare an all-in-one tool vs multiple specialized tools, which more accurately reflects the comparison of ajax vs get, post, and load. Thanks for the suggestion!</sub>

Comment: what if Joe doesn't use a hammer, but some wonderful all-in-one tool? :) Sorta like a swiss army knive :D

Comment: You know, the all-in-one tool makes a better analogy. I will update my post.

Comment: But then Anna realizes that each of her single-purpose tools is actually the very same all-in one tool as Joe's, but with all other attachments broken off or taped shut. She goes to the bar, orders a drink, and ponders this for a while.